# OpenCV 2.4.11 does not work on wareable decice?

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, wear-os

I am using openCV 2.4.11 for face-detection purpose and have problem with the camera on my target. The code works perfectly on tablet android-4.4.2 and phone android-5.1.1, but when ever I try to execute the same code on the smart watches android-4.4.2 it doesn't work. It shows a warning saying that "it seems that your device does not support camera (or it is locked).Application will be closed"

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing Android Wear devices have a camera and the message you are receiving is very descriptive of the issue.

Comment: sorry sir, but the smartwatch or the wareable device i am working on has a single camera.

Comment: Is it running android wear? What watch is that?